# Google Maps forEach with setMap to set polyline visiblity (error: setMap is not a function)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set the visibility of polylines based on a property. I use forEach to iterate over the features in the GeoJson data but when I try and call setMap on the array, I get type error: setMap is not a function. I have also tried pushing the resulting features into a new array with the same result.

```
map.data.loadGeoJson(
  'data/trails2018.geojson', {},
  function(features) {
    console.log("loadGeoJson callback "+features.length);
    map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
      var skill = feature.getProperty('skill_leve');
        if (skill == 'ADVANCED'){ 
            feature.setMap(null);
        }
    }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control the visibility of features on a [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) with the style property `visible`.

```
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var visible = false;
    if (feature.getProperty('skill_level')) {
      var skill = feature.getProperty('skill_level');
      if (skill == 'ADVANCED') {
        visible = true;
      }
    }
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      strokeColor: "blue",
      visible: visible
    });
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f9h9pk5h/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.55865, -46.65953),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var features = map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  console.log("addGeoJson returns " + features.length);
  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    var skill = feature.getProperty('skill_level');
    if (skill == 'ADVANCED') {
      // feature.setMap(null);
    }
  });
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var visible = false;
    if (feature.getProperty('skill_level')) {
      var skill = feature.getProperty('skill_level');
      if (skill == 'ADVANCED') {
        visible = true;
      }
    }
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      strokeColor: "blue",
      visible: visible
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "skill_level": "ADVANCED"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-43.48283, -23.02487],
          [-43.65903, -23.55888]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 2,
        "skill_level": "BEGINNER"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-46.65953, -23.02487],
          [-46.65903, -23.55888]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you very much!